# What does the "most derived object" mean?

Tags: c++

The C++03 Standard states §1.8 [intro.object]/4:

> If a complete object, a data member (9.2), or an array element is of
>   class type, its type is considered the most derived class, to
>   distinguish it from the class type of any base class subobject; an
>   object of a most derived class type is called a most derived object.

Can anyone shed some light on the "most derived object"? Some examples would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quote is defining the meaning of *most derived class* to be the class of the object being instantiated. While an object can be of *many* types, as inheritance models the *is-a* relationship, it will only have one *most derived class*.

With an example:

```
class base {};
class derived : base {};
class base2 {};
class mostderived : derived, base2 {};

mostderived md;
```

The object `md` is of *most derived class* `mostderived`, although it is also of types `base`, `derived` and `base1`. When talking about `md`, there is a subobject of type `base`, a subobject of type `derived` (that includes the subobject of type `base`), and a subobject of type `base2`, but only one *most derived object* that is `md` of type `mostderived`.

Comment: follow-up to this: if there are two such classes, `mostderived1` and `mostderived2`, and subsequently two objects `md1` and `md2`, are they both considered "most-derived"?