# Is every "complete" object a "most-derived" object?

Tags: c++, class, object, language-lawyer

Per [[intro.object]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2.sentence-3):

> [..] An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a complete object [..].

So consider this snippet of code:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};
struct MostDerived : Derived {};
```

I can't understand the wording in this quote from the standard:

[[object.intro]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#6):

> If a complete object, a member subobject, or an array element is of class type, its type is considered the most derived class [..] An object of a most derived class type or of a non-class type is called a most derived object.

From the quote what I understand is that a type of a complete object is of "most-derived" class type. I stopped here, I really do not understand the rest of the wording.

- Per the question ["What does the "most derived object" mean?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241637/what-does-the-most-derived-object-mean) I think that (correct me if I am wrong), objects of type "most-derived" class *only*, like `MostDerived`, are called "most-derived" objects. Is this true?
- If I have created an object of `Base` like this: `Base b_obj = Base()`, is the object `b_obj` a "most-derived" object?
- If I have created an object of `Derived` like this: `Derived d_obj = Derived()`, is the object `d_obj` also a "most-derived" object?
- Does the word "derived" in "most-derived" mean that the object is an object of a class like `MostDerived`, or mean that the object has no class subobject in it?

Comment: See also [this editorial issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2950). The terms are supposed to describe a relation between objects, but the current wording doesn't define them as such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Per the question "What does the "most derived object" mean?" I think that (correct me if I am wrong), objects of type "most-derived" class only, like MostDerived, are called "most-derived" objects. Does this true?.

"*Most derived class*" is supposed to be dependent on the object under consideration. It is not a property of the class as such.

> if I have created an object of Base like this: Base b_obj = Base(), Is the object b_obj is "most-derived" object?

Yes, `b_obj` is a variable and as such a complete object. A complete object is always a most-derived object.

> if I have created an object of Derived like this: Derived d_obj = Derived(), Is the object d_obj is also a "most-derived" object?

Same as above applies.

> Is the word "derived" in "most-derived" mean that the object is an object of a class like MostDerived, or mean that the object has no class subobject in it?

"*most-derived*" means that there is no other object of which the object under consideration is a base class subobject. This is again not a property of classes themselves, but depends on the concrete instance of the class. If for example a `Derived` object is created with `new Derived`, then it contains a `Base` base class subobject and this subobject is not a most-derived object. However the `Derived` object is the most-derived object, since there isn't e.g. any `MostDerived` object of which it is a base class subobject.

> Is every "complete" object is "most-derived" object

Yes, every complete object is a most-derived object. But the reverse is not true. For example

```
struct A {
    Base b;
};

A a;
```

`a` is an object of type `A` and itself a most-derived object and a complete object, but `a.b` is also a most-derived object, although not a complete object.

Answer (score 2):

1. An object is not a class.
2. An object is an instantiation of a class, an array, or built-in-type.
3. Subobjects are class member objects, array elements, or base classes of an object.
4. Derived objects (and most-derived objects) only make sense in the context of class inheritance.

```
void foo() {
    int i = 0; // complete object, but not most-derived (not class type)
}

class A {
   int i = 0; // non complete object, not most-derived
}

void bar() {
    A a; // complete object, but not derived, so can't be "most derived"
}

class B : A { }

void biz() {
   B b; // complete object, derived object, and most-derived object
}
```

---

> Is every "complete" object is "most-derived" object

No. A most-derived object is an object of a most-derived class, and a most-derived class must be of a class type. Objects may be of class type, but non-class type objects also exist.

- Every complete object of class-type is a most-derived object only if that class inherits.
- A most-derived object may be a subobject, so you cannot infer object completeness from most-derivedness (however, you can infer that the most-derived object is of class type).

---

> So if I have created an object of Base like this: `Base b_obj = Base()`, Is the object `b_obj` is "most-derived" object?

Yes. The most-derived object of `b_obj` is an object of type `Base`. This is not necessarily a complete object, however, since this could be a class member definition. Again, complete is not synonymous with most-derived.

---

> Also if I have created an object of Derived like this: `Derived d_obj = Derived()`, Is the object `d_obj` is also a "most-derived" object?

Yes. The most-derived object of `d_obj` is an object of type `Derived`.

---

If you have an object created as type `MostDerived`:

```
MostDerived md;
```

- It is an object of type `MostDerived`
- It is an object of type `Derived`
- It is an object of type `Base`
- If it is not a member subobject, then it is a complete object
- Its most-derived object is of type `MostDerived`
- It has a subobject of type `Derived`, which is neither a complete object nor a most-derived object
- Its subobject of type `Derived` has a subobject of type `Base`, which is neither a complete object nor a most-derived object.

Comment: Thanks, JohnFilleau. Can you add a point that states whether or not objects you have declared `md` and `d` and `b` are "most-derived" objects or not? That's basically what's I am asking for

Comment: "_Yes. Complete object and most-derived object are synonymous."_: There are most-derived objects which are not complete objects (e.g. members and array elements). "_It is an object of type_" sounds wrong, since `it` seems to refer to the variable which is one object only (with the most-derived type).

Comment: @user17732522 I'd believe that. I'm just kind of winging it hoping someone who knows better will come and fix it.

Comment: @JohnFilleau It seems otherwise correct to me, which is why I am only trying to correct your answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: If you can please answer "*Is the word "derived" in "most-derived" mean that the object is an object of a most-derived class, like class MostDerived, or mean that the object has no class subobject in it?*". I am actually know the answer (thanks to @user17732522), but it might be helpful for others.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Non-class type objects can be most-derived object as well (and as far as I can tell _always_ are).

Comment: @JohnFilleau That seems to have been the original meaning of the term (and the intuitive one), but it was changed with [CWG 513](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#513) because the use of the term in the standard didn't match this definition.

Comment: @user17732522 I am learning so much here. Thank you for the language lessons. Was that proposal adopted though?

Comment: I'm also about to eat and enjoy the rest of my Sunday. If someone wants to edit this, or even copy-paste and fix it in their own answer, feel free. I don't care about the points.

Comment: @JohnFilleau The linked page contains only the accepted defect reports, although I think the final wording may differ from the proposed one. But you can just look at the wording in the current draft at https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object.